# Compare two tables and extract missing element per date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Hi everyone I have a problem with a SQL query and I can not find a solution.

In my database I have two tables, Mytable1 and Mytable2. Mytable1 contains columns idCalendar, idPlayer, datePlaying and Mytable2 contains columns idPlayer and namePlayer.

I want to extract foreach date in Mytable1 the names of players who did not play.

For example
Mytable1 (contains player and playing date):

`idCalendar|idPlayer|datePlaying`

```
1         |     1  | 05/01/2012
2         |     2  | 06/01/2012
3         |     3  | 08/01/2012
4         |     2  | 05/01/2012
```

Mytable2 (contains all player names) :

`idPlayer|namePlayer`

```
1  | P1
2  | P2
3  | P3
4  | P4
```

I'd like to create a view that displays the following result :

ViewResult (players who haven't played by date):

`datePlaying | playerName`

```
05/01/2012  | P2
05/01/2012  | P3
06/01/2012  | P1
06/01/2012  | P3
08/01/2012  | P1
08/01/2012  | P2
```

As you can see I need result with this information: 
 - in 05/01/2012 P2 and P3 haven't played.
 - in 06/01/2012 P1 and P3 haven't played.
 - in 08/01/2012 P1 and P2 haven't played.

I hope I have been clear enough. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks to me like P2 DID play on 05/01/2012. Is this just a typo? And how come P4 doesn't show up at all in your ViewResult -- they haven't played on any dates. Finally, is ViewResult supposed to show EVERY SINGLE POSSIBLE DATE, along with all the players who did not play on that date? Or is it only showing dates that are in Mytable1?

Comment: @Jeremy Goodell thank you for your reply. Yes i need to display only showing dates that are in Mytable1 with name of players who did not play in this date

Comment: Are the id's in Mytable2 correct? P2 and P4 both have the same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something as simple as this would work.

```
select
    d.datePlaying, p.namePlayer
from
    table2 p
cross join 
    (select distinct datePlaying from table1) d
left join
    table1 t on t.idPlayer = p.idPlayer and t.datePlaying = d.datePlaying
where
    t.idPlayer is null
```

As a side note what happens if you have a date where non of the players played? You wouldnt have an entry in table2. Do you care or should there be a 3rd table to represent dates that any of the players should have played. This dates table would be used to replace my alias 'd' cross-joined table.

Comment: thank you so much it's great! Especially the idea of ​​the third table, you anticipate my needs.

Comment: @mouters: +1 for your answer. As far as I can tell, our queries return identical result sets. Do you know if there is a performance benefit of one over the other? (I don't know -- just curious.)

Comment: @HeadOfCatering, difficult to say without running it through SMS and displaying the execution path details. Usually when I assume one query will perform better than another the sql server query optimizer proves me wrong. My gut reaction to your query would be that sql server would have to table-scan for the results of Hashbytes() function especially since you're concatenating the date and name fields. BUT as I said the query optimizer manages to prove me wrong everytime, so they are probably equal :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a db handy on this computer, so I can't test this at the moment -- I will keep working on it.

```
SELECT     DISTINCT a.datePlaying, b.playerName
FROM       Mytable1 a
INNER JOIN Mytable2 b
        ON a.idPlayer = b.idPlayer
WHERE      NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT idPlayer
           FROM   Mytable1 a2
           WHERE  a.datePlaying = a2.datePlaying)
ORDER BY   a.datePlaying
```